# Права на шифрованный раздел для www-data

Tags: apache, права, sshfs, debian

По замыслу на хосте IDE Eclipse с рабочим каталогом workspase. Внутри сайт. С помощью sshfs этот сайт монтируется внутрь виртуальной машины с apache. В хоум-каталог обычного пользователя. [Туториал](http://itbuben.org/blog/Unix-way/1807.html) по которому делал. Пользователь имеет доступ в каталог, может создавать или удалять файлы. А вот apache выдает 403.

```
tr@hst:~/workspase$ ls -lитого 12drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Дек  4  2011 localhost_lexpro
```

Ни chown, ни chmod, ни chgrp внутри каталога не помогают. www-data также был добавлен в группу fuse. Единственным выходом пока вижу попробовать монтирование от пользователя www-data, успех сомнителен.

Есть варианты?

Comment: Вполне возможно дело в SELinux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение

```
echo user_allow_other >> /etc/fuse.conf
```

Монтировать, соответственно, тоже параметром `-o allow_other`